# How to find the equation of a hyperplane in $\mathbb R^4$ that contains $3$ given vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry, vectors

> Find the equation of a hyperplane in $\mathbb R^4$ that contains $3$ given vectors. The vectors are:
>   $$v_1 = (1,0,-1,0),\quad  
> v_2 = (0,1,1,1),\quad
> v_3 = (1,1,-1,0) $$

I've found the equation in parametric form ($s$ and $t$ are scalars):

$$x=-s+1,\quad
y=s+t,\quad
z=2s-1,\quad
w=s$$

The answer in the back of the book says the answer is: $x_1+x_3-x_4=0$.

**How would I convert my answer into an equation for the hyper plane?**

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @PeterFranek I tried plugging the vectors back in but that got me 0=0. I noticed that if s=0 and t=0 The answer would be x1+x3=0 which is close but that might be a fluke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your parametric form isn't right: the  hyperplane is $3$-dimensional (the given vectors are linearly independent), so it would need three parameters: 
$$(r,s,t) \mapsto rv_1+sv_2+tv_3$$ 
But this is not what you want anyway. You want a non-parametric equation: 
$$c_1x_1+c_2x_2+c_3x_3+c_4x_4=0 \tag{1}$$
It must be such that the given vectors are contained in the hyperplane, meaning
$$
\begin{cases} c_1-c_3&=0\\ c_2+c_3+c_4&=0\\ c_1+c_2-c_3&=0 \end{cases}
$$
Solve this system, and you'll have the coefficients for (1).

Comment: I solved it and got c1=-s, c2=0, c3=-s, c4,=s. s is a scalar. I can see that it multiplied by -1 would give you the answer but why multiply it by -1? Where does the s go?

Comment: So, there are infinitely many solutions (one for each value of $s$), which means there are infinitely many ways to write down the equation of this hyperplane. You can use $s=1$ and get $-x_1-x_3+x_4=0$. Or you can use $s=-7$ and get $7x_1+7x_3-7x_4=0$. These are both correct answers; they are equivalent to each other. The answer in the book is putting $s=-1$. Just because the author felt it would be neater to not begin the equation with $-$ sign.